# How to send data from Spring Actuator health endpoint to influxDB

Tags: influxdb, spring-boot-actuator

I have a few apps on the cloud using Spring Boot 2.4 and 2.5. `/health` and `/prometheus` Actuator endpoints are exposed. I have Prometheus scraping `/prometheus` endpoint and sending that data to InfluxDB. I need to also send data from `/health` endpoint to InfluxDB. I need this to be able to have UP and DOWN data for the app and third parties (e.g. DB). I am trying to avoid custom development for this. How do I do it?

Example of what I am looking for is with Prometheus - enable `/prometheus` endpoint in every app and configure Prometheus to scrape the data.

Options I checked:

1. Add custom data to '/prometheus` endpoint. Downside - needs custom development per multiple apps which I am trying to avoid.
2. Send data to InfluxDB directly from the app (likely using Micrometer). Downsides - custom development, apps need to care about sending, not only their purpose.
3. Use InfluxDB scrapers to scrape the data from the apps. Scrapers expect Prometheus data format, but `/health` outputs JSON. Downsides - I didn't find a way to change data format of `/health`, no automatic discovery of newly added instances of apps.
4. Use existing Prometheus to scrape `/health` as it does with `/prometheus`. Same problem as above - `/health` endpoint uses JSON instead of Prometheus format.

Is there a way to send data provided by Spring Boot `/health` Actuator endpoint to InfluxDB without custom development per every app?